# Explicit homeomorphism between triangle and square

Tags: general-topology

Which is the explicit homeomorphism between the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and the triangle $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \,\, 0 \le x,y \le 1, y \ge x\}$?

Answer (score 5):

I'll leave it to you to crunch out if you want a literal formula, but here's a useful general method of obtaining homeomorphisms for polygons and polytopes:

Draw a square and a triangle centered at the origin, with the triangle small enough so as to be contained entirely inside of the square.  Next, at the origin, draw a ray for each angle $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, .  This ray will intersect both the triangle and the square at exactly one point (and every point on both polygons will be accounted for).  Send that point on the triangle to that point on the square.

Think also about why this actually is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The question was about 'filled' polygons, not just the perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the (solid) square is homeomorphic to the unit disc.

Show that the (solid) triangle is homeomorphic to the unit disc.

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued periodic map on the real numbers repeating over intervals of 2π radians. Assume that $f(x) > 0$.

THEN, using polar coordinates, the map

(1) $\rho e^{i\theta} \mapsto f(\theta) \rho e^{i\theta}$

is a homeomorphism of two-dimensional space.

So you have to explicitly describe two periodic functions, one to take the square to the disc and one to take the triangle to the disc. Then you compose two bijections to get your homeomorphism between the square and triangle.

I am going to describe a homeomorphism that takes the compact region enclosed by

$y=1-x$

$x=0$

$y=0$

and transforms it onto the compact region

$x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ with both $x$ and $y$ non-negative numbers.

Our function $f$ here is defined only on the domain $[0, \pi /2]$:

$f(\theta) = cos(\theta) + sin(\theta)$

and using it in (1) does what we want.

You can elaborate on this work to get an explicit  homeomorphism of your square region onto the unit disc.